# Which sentence sounds more natural "unique and distinct items" or "distinct items with unique personality"?

Tags: grammar

We are attracted to **unique and distinct items** that only I can enjoy and experience rather than items that are commonly seen and easily available around us.

We are attracted to **distinct items with unique personality** that only I can enjoy and experience rather than items that are commonly seen and easily available around us.

Could anyone tell me which sounds more natural and if they mean the same?

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence "unique" and "distinct" are essentially synonyms, so you should not use both.

The second is more natural. There the item is distinct and its personality is unique, so there is no redundancy. You are telling your reader why these items attract you.

But the second is clumsy for other reasons. "We" are attracted but "I" can enjoy seems wrong. "Enjoy and experience" is awkward. "Items" appears twice - a pronoun  might be better. "Around us" seems to me unnecessary after "easily available".